# Шаблоны и явная специализация. C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть такой шаблон.

```
template<class T>
T maxn(T *, int);
```

и спецализация для `char*`

```
template<> char* maxn(char**, int);
```

Теперь хотелось бы добавить еще и `const`, т.е. `T maxn(const T *, int);`, но после добавления в спецализации `const` выдается ошибка, т.е. `maxn` подчеркивается красным.

```
template<> char* maxn<char*>(const char**, int);
```

Почему? Кто объяснит?

Comment: это функция, которая возаращает первый аргумент? Если так, то оно подсвечивается из-за того, что у вас первый аргумент константный, а вы пытаетесь вернуть не константное значение. Добавьте `const` перед возвращаемым значением

Comment: нет не первый аргумент

Comment: в таком случае продемонстрируйте тело функции

Comment: Так `const char *` должен быть везде на месте `T`, т.е. `template<> const char * maxn< const char * >(const char * *, int);`

Comment: тела даже нету. Это только прототипы. Но могу сейчас написать.

Comment: нет. Добавление const не помогает. Я пробовал не раз.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам вообще нужна специализация? Можно просто перегрузить функцию: `char *maxn(char **, int);`.

Comment: В задании в книге написано создать спецализацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну не получив полноценный ответ тут я решил задать тот же вопрос в английском StackOverflow. И мне там ответили

```
template<>
char* maxn<char*>(char* const *, int);
```

Вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496005/templates-and-explicit-specializations/51496124#51496124) на ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Специализация шаблона должна соответствовать главному шаблону, который она специализирует.

Во-первых, вы в своей специализации явно указали шаблонный параметр `T == char *`. Но ваша первая специализация уже была сделана для такого значения параметра `T`. Невозможно сделать еще одну специализацию для того же самого набора значений параметров. (И с чего это вдруг решили явно указать значение параметра, если в первой специализации вы этого не делали?)

Во-вторых, из значения шаблонного параметра `T == char *` сразу следует, что параметр функции `T *` должен иметь тип `char **`. А у вас написано - `const char **`. Это уже противоречит главному шаблону.

В-третьих, у вас в главном шаблоне ясно написано, что тип возвращаемого значения связан с типом параметра функции (`T` и `T *` соответственно). Это означает, что при типе параметра `const char **`, возвращаемое значение никак не может быть `char *`. Это тоже противоречит главному шаблону.

Другими словами, у вашего главного шаблона никак не может быть такой специализации.

Вот такую специализацию вы можете сделать

```
template<> const char* maxn(const char**, int);

// Она же
// template<> const char* maxn<const char*>(const char**, int);
```

но никак не то, что у вас сейчас.

А дальше все уже зависит от того, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Из вашего вопроса не ясно, зачем вам понадобилась такая "специализация". Может вам нужна перегрузка, а не специализация?

```
// Два перегруженных шаблона
template<class T> T maxn(T *, int);
template<class T> T maxn(const T *, int);
```

или

```
// Шаблон и перегруженная функция
template<class T> T maxn(T *, int);
char* maxn(const char**, int);
```

Comment: скорее нужна перегрузка